# Java Enum Database mapping

Tags: java, hibernate-mapping

I have mapped a column in Mysql DB to enum in java. Have added a new value in Java for Enum but not in the database yet. And when I run my junit test by creating a mock dataset I get the following exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown ordinal value for enum class PromotionTypeEnum

Comment: Show some code, preferrably a running example.

Comment: Well, since I'm a human, not a machine, I understood his question enough to assist. Stack overflow rejections because of excessively high standards do NOT help users in search for a quick steering answer.

Answer (score 1):

does your table's row's cell have a legal value for the enum?
see also http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/hibernate-enum-type-mapping-example

Comment: Sorry the whole issue was because the Enum class starts the count from 0 and I was looking for an element which was not in the Enum size.